# Change text of a linkbutton in a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, findcontrol

I have a repeater which displays comments related to a post.

I want to add some functionality where when the user click on the link it goes from:

*report this post*

to

*post has been flagged*

how do I access the specific lnkButton?  Obviously in ItemDataBound this is easily done, but in the click method I'm not sure how I would do it.

Do I need to do something like:

I tried something like this;

```
LinkButton lb = repeater.FindControl(LINK_BUTTON_UNIQUE_ID) as LinkButton;
lb.Text = "blah blah blah";
```

but lb is always null.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you saving the flag status to a db? If so, why not just refresh the repeater after the postback and not worry about it?

Comment: yeah I was saving the flag status to a db

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the source parameter of the click handler?

```
protected void MyLinkButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton b = sender as LinkButton;
    b.Text = "Some Text";
}
```